# How are you supposed to use the with() method with Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

```
/**
 * Set the relationships that should be eager loaded.
 *
 * @param  dynamic  $relations
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|static
 */
public function with($relations)
{
    if (is_string($relations)) $relations = func_get_args();

    $eagers = $this->parseRelations($relations);

    $this->eagerLoad = array_merge($this->eagerLoad, $eagers);

    return $this;
}
```

I can't find any documents on how to use this method. What is `$relations` suppose to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation name or the method name that defines the relation:

if you have a model as

```
class Post extends Eloquent {

    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

}
```

You do

```
$posts = Post::with('author')->all();
```

And it will eager load the users in your posts rows.